# Alter table to add a foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am using MySQL.

I have an existing table named `school` with hundreds of rows data be populated. Now I have another table named `student`, its **primary key** is "**sid**".

I would like to **alter** my `school` table to have a foreign key reference to a `student`.

I tried the following sql statement:

```
ALTER TABLE school ADD FOREIGN KEY (sid) REFERENCES student(sid);
```

But I get error:

```
ERROR 1072 (42000): Key column 'sid' doesn't exist in table
```

What is the correct way to alter table to add a foreign key to another table?

Answer (score 3):

You have to add the column `sid` on your table first.

```
ALTER TABLE school ADD COLUMN sid [INT, VARCHAR2(10];
ALTER TABLE school ADD FOREIGN KEY (sid) REFERENCES student(sid);
```

**PS:** I put `[INT, VARCHAR2(10]` because I don't know what type student(sid) is. Just change to the correct one.

Comment: You should also add an index on that column first I think?

Comment: I think it depends on the use. If it will be much requested, it's common to add.

Comment: Well, I've looked it up: it doesn't depend on the actual use, it depends on the engine you use. If you use InnoDB you can only add foreign keys to indexed columns. (see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html : _InnoDB permits a foreign key to reference any index column or group of columns. However, in the referenced table, there must be an index where the referenced columns are listed as the first columns in the same order._)

Comment: @Nanne What I mean is that adding index on tables requires more disk space (see [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-physical-structure.html)). If the queries are performing good, there's no need to do so; like if the table is rarely requested.

Comment: I know that,  but what that link says is that in order to be able to define the foreign  key at all, it is mandatory. The manual I linked kinda says it: you can only define them on an indexed column

Answer (score 1):

where do you want to link your foreign key?

it seems that you missed the key to link against in the school table:

As far as i can imagine you want to link a student to his school.

So what i'd do is to add a column to the student table:

```
ALTER TABLE STUDENT
ADD COLUMN SCHOOL_ID INT NOT NULL;
```

then i'd create the foreign key in STUDENT table to point to SCHOOL

```
ALTER TABLE STUDENT
ADD FOREIGN KEY (F_SCHOOL_ID) REFERENCES SCHOOL(ID);
```

This is the best way and not the other way round.